# Woocommerce Sending Custom New Order Email to Custom Email Address

Tags: php, wordpress, email, customization

I got a quick question as I've been researching a couple of hours and have not found a suitable answer.

Id like to send a new type of e-mail when a new order is made and send it to the email address provided in a custom check-out field.

I've implemented Woocommerce and added extra checkout-fields via the plugin (Checkout Field Editor. 
One of these check-out fields holds an email address (field name is [client_email]).

I also managed to create a new type of e-mail via the Woo Custom Emails Plugin.

The only problem I have is to set the recipient for this email with the input from the custom checkout field [client_email].

Any thoughts or solutions?

Many thanks!

I'd find this little snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'processing_order_replacement_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function processing_order_replacement_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Set HERE your replacement recipient email(s)… (If multiple, separate them by a coma)
    $recipient = '<email adress>';
    return $recipient;
}
```

And this is the e-mail template file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

$email_heading = get_option( 'ec_woocommerce_customer_processing_order_heading' );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php echo get_option( 'ec_woocommerce_customer_processing_order_main_text' ); ?>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: Dear Mark, post your code otherwise SO can't help you out. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also..complete the tour.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Actualy i don't have any custom code running at the moment.

Comment: That's a start Mark. If the code you're using is multiple files just add them into your question. No problems with that. If its large files with thousands of lines... then extract the essential code and post, the rest of it goes into attachments.

Comment: Ok, well give me a sec to point it all out.

Comment: Well done Mark.. this way people can test run it on their own system and give you constructive feedback. (my reviewing task is done for now :-)

Comment: Ok, i've put up some of the code. What more files are good to post??

Comment: That's for the experts in the php field to decide. My expertise is python and some other funny biological things (you can check my profile if you click on my tagname). My task was to decide if your question was salvageable or not.. and it was. Enjoy your stay on SO ;-)

Comment: Ahh i get it. Thanks a lot for getting me started! Have a great day!